# Strange NoCase error in .htaccess

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

For some years I've been using the same .htaccess to control url rewrite on apache, however now I'm getting the following error:

```
[Wed May 08 17:14:16 2013] [warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored.

[Wed May 08 17:14:16 2013] [warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-d' is not supported and will be ignored.

[Wed May 08 17:14:16 2013] [warn] RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-l' is not supported and will be ignored.
```

My .htaccess is as follows:

```
# << Friendly URL's

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php

# >> Friendly URL's

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com\.br$ [OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com\.br$
#RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\.br\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com.br$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com.br/$1 [R=301]
```

Since I don't have great knowledge of .htaccess usage I don't know what's heappening. In truth, I've learned just a little about .htaccess long ago to build this file, however it's not working anymore. Can someone please give me a help on how to correct this error?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: If you are hosted by BlueHost: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/rewritecond-nocase-option-for-non-regex-pattern-f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **warning** messages do not apply to any of the lines in the .htaccess file you showed, as there are no **NoCase** (**NC**) options set for any of the statements.

They must be coming from some other .htaccess file or apache configuration file,  probably not related to you if you are sharing the server with others. In any case the warning messages do not indicate any serious problem, just that the NC option was entered where it was not needed and has no effect.

If it is your own server or if you are in control of  it, you can check these other files and  look for `RewriteCond` statements that contain `-d`, `-f`, or `-l` and are having the `NC` option. And then safely remove the `NC` option to get rid of the warning messages. For example change

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

More information about these warning messages can be found [here](http://www.adrianworlddesign.com/Knowledge-Base/Web-Hosting/Apache-Web-Server/NoCase-option-not-supported).